# How to use New-Item with $Version to create a text file

Tags: powershell, new-item

I have pulled some information from the registry using `Get-ItemPropertyValue` and would like to use this to create a text file with that value.

```
$Version = (Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name 'DisplayVersion')
```

Example output - 21H1

Trying to use `New-Item` with `$Version` output to create a text file, `21H1.txt`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to better understand what is required for a good question title, and the level of detail required in the question and how to tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your variable in an expandable string, and pass the resulting string value to `New-Item`'s `-Name` parameter

```
New-Item -Name "${Version}.txt"
```